# Get the correct number of bytes from NetworkStream.Read() and place them in a buffer

Tags: c#, networking

I'm trying to get my client application to read a response from the server, and I'm really having trouble grasping a certain concept here.

According to the research I've done, you **must** have the length of the bytes to read from a `NetworkStream` before you can actually read the data. This makes very little sense to me. How are you supposed to know how much data is coming in before it even gets there?

This code:

```
using (var stream = client.GetStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Flush();

    Console.WriteLine("Data sent.\n");

    Console.WriteLine("Reading response...\n");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

reads 1024 bytes into a buffer with a set size. So what if the response from the server has *more* than 1024 bytes? Then what?

If somebody could help me grasp this concept, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: That's why the server should tell you how many bytes it's sending.  Or, just keep reading until you run out of byes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop whilst the NetworkStream.DataAvailable is true; see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of pre-agreed scheme (a protocol) between the sender and the receiver for determining the "end of message".

Usually this is done by starting the message with a header that includes the length of message. For example, both parties can agree that the first 4 bytes determine the length of the incoming message, so the receiver reads that many bytes.

Another way would be having a specific sequence of bytes that signifies the end of message. For instance, the receiver keeps reading in until it sees the ascii bytes of `<EOF>`.

Do not use `DataAvailable` because it is quite possible that you receive the message in chunks, so `DataAvailable` can turn false before you have received the full message.